# Changing view upon button click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I am trying to display different views upon button clicks. Here is what I currently have but when I click the button nothing changes and I remain at the home page. I am trying to use $location.path('/path');

app.js

```
    var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/", { templateUrl: "views/news.html", controller: "mainCtrl"})
            .when("/hello", { templateUrl: "views/hello.html", controller: "helloCtrl"})

    });

app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.setNews = () => { 
        $scope.showHello = false;
        $scope.newsactive = "butactive"
        $scope.helloactive = ""
    };
});

    app.controller("helloCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.setHello = () => { 
            $location.path('/hello');
            $scope.showHello = false;
            $scope.helloactive = "butactive"
            $scope.newsactive = ""
        };
    });
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div>
        <div ng-include="'views/title.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'views/navbar.html'"></div>
    </div>

        <div ng-view></div>

    <div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>

</body>
```

navbar.html

```
<div class="navbar">
    <button id="newsbutton" ng-click="setNews()" ng-class="newsactive">News</button>    
    <button id="aboutbutton" ng-click="setHello()" ng-class="helloactive">Hello</button>    
</div>
```

hello.html

```
<div class="content">
    <div ng-hide="showHello" id="hello">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `setHello` function within your `mainCtrl`.

Currently you are trying to access the `setHello` function defined inside the `helloCtrl` from the html that has the scope of `mainCtrl`. Correcting the scope will work.

Hope this helps :)